# Copy command to copy the content of one directory to another

Tags: linux, terminal

To copy the content of a directory to another , we use the command :

```
cr -r <src dir> <dst dir>
```

The flag -r is used to copy the content recursively. My question is what is exactly the meaning of -r , still I cant understand the word recursively ?

Comment: Have you Google the meaning of the word `recursively`?

Comment: @NasirRiley Yes but I didn't understand it in the context of directories and cd command

Comment: Think of directory as a tree, with subdirectories as branch nodes and files as leaves.  Make a directory for branches and copy the file for leaves.

Comment: Fix your typo, `cp -r <src dir> <dst dir>`.
In most Linux/Unix systems, recursively means it will traverse the directory tree to perform the action.

Comment: A simple use of recursion can be found in https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have friends in your neighbour house and you want to bring them to your house. It is easy you just call them and they will come to your house. Now if you want to call friend of your friend than you can simply tell your friend to do the job for you to bring that friend to your house. Same for the directory if you have files in the directory  then cp will copy it to destination but there is directory then it will tell that directory to move that files to destination. That is why you need recurcive.